# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to convert the below to integers

I have a variable p which is the below

`array([0.09641092, 0.02070604, 0.21679783, ..., 0.06453979, 0.02907993, 0.12129478])`

I want to convert the numbers based on a threshold

`thres = 0.5`

then convert

`p1 =  np.int(p > thres)`

but i get the below error

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert the type of the *array*. Accordingly, do this instead:

```
(p > thres).astype(np.int)
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.int` is just `int`, the normal Python built-in type. I think it's only even in the `numpy` namespace for backward compatibility. It's not a NumPy type, and you can't perform type conversion on arrays by calling it.

`np.int_` is the NumPy type for the dtype `int` values get converted to by default, and it's the one used when you do something like `some_array.astype(int)`. It corresponds to C `long`. `np.int_`, you can call to type-convert whole arrays:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([True, False, True])
>>> numpy.int_(x)
array([1, 0, 1])
```

but it's more usual to use `astype`:

```
>>> x.astype(int)
array([1, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.09641092, 0.02070604, 0.21679783, 0.06453979, 0.02907993, 0.12129478])
t = 0.05
for i in range(len(a)):
if(a[i]>t):
    print(a[i])
```

output:

```
0.09641092
0.21679783
0.06453979
0.12129478
```

or

```
print(np.int(a[i]))
```

output:

```
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: I don't think that answers the question that OP (original poster) asked. They want to change all the values, not just select based on threshold.